# how to use multiple query in sql

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to show count and row table in one query, but when I run this it shows 0 rows and it does not show the count.

```
   <?php

   include "connect_db.php";
   $query = "SELECT COUNT(*) AS numberOfRows FROM wp_cf7_data, wp_cf7_data_entry WHERE wp_cf7_data.id=wp_cf7_data_entry.data_id and cf7_id = 1470 AND name = \"your-name\" and wp_cf7_data.created BETWEEN '2017-11-27 08:54:39' and '2017-12-03 08:54:39'
   UNION
   SELECT * FROM wp_cf7_data, wp_cf7_data_entry WHERE wp_cf7_data.id=wp_cf7_data_entry.data_id and cf7_id = 1470 AND name = \"your-name\" and wp_cf7_data.created BETWEEN '2017-11-27 08:54:39' and '2017-12-03 08:54:39'
   ";





   $result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);

   if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
       // output data of each row
       while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
         echo $row['numberOfRows'];
           echo "id: " . $row["id"]. " - Name: " . $row["cf7_id"]. " " . $row["name"]. "<br>";

       }
   } else {
       echo "0 results";
   }

   mysqli_close($conn);
   ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your query seems potentially wrong .. because  could not have the same number of column in the two select you use for union try using a cooresponding number of column sin both the query

```
$query = "SELECT COUNT(*) AS numberOfRows 
      FROM wp_cf7_data, wp_cf7_data_entry 
      WHERE wp_cf7_data.id=wp_cf7_data_entry.data_id and cf7_id = 1470 AND name = \"your-name\" and wp_cf7_data.created BETWEEN '2017-11-27 08:54:39' and '2017-12-03 08:54:39'
      UNION
      SELECT count(*) 
      FROM wp_cf7_data, wp_cf7_data_entry 
      WHERE wp_cf7_data.id=wp_cf7_data_entry.data_id and cf7_id = 1470 AND name = \"your-name\" and wp_cf7_data.created BETWEEN '2017-11-27 08:54:39' and '2017-12-03 08:54:39'
```

";

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that you're getting an error from MySQL, which you're not capturing (that's something that you should check on because your code in general should be written to handle errors.

The problem here is that you're trying to `UNION` two result sets that don't have the same columns. `COUNT(*)` is a single integer column, while `SELECT *` is going to return you multiple columns.

Instead, just use your second query after the `UNION` (remove the entire `SELECT COUNT(*)`) then check the count from the resultset that you get back using `mysql_num_rows`. I don't program in php, but I'm sure that you can find examples of how to use this with a quick Google search.

Some other quick notes:

Never use `SELECT *`. ALWAYS list out the column list that you're hoping to return. If you use `SELECT *` then not only is your code not clear, but if the table design changes at any point it will suddenly break all of your code.

Also, use explicit `JOIN`s (`INNER` or `OUTER` as appropriate). Don't just put your tables in the `FROM` clause.